# Switching visibility (eye) between selected meshes via Python

Tags: modeling, python, 3d-view

is it possible to switching visibility between multiple selected meshes?
I have a mesh and the same slightly modified and I need to switch between them to see what is best for my needs.

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/151270/31447, https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/197072/31447

Comment: If some one is looking for this too
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/160694/how-to-toggle-selected-objects-visibility-with-h-shortcut-as-in-maya